# Parsing XML to match comments and text according to tag ids

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

(UPDATED): Added code to match values according to their ids. Question: Why are the matching ids u'1' and 'u'0' in both dictionaries not recognized?

(GOAL for Code):
I'm writing a script that takes commented text from a .docx file and matches it to comments via xml tag ids. I've managed to extract the comment tags, text and ids. I now need to match these up. My strategy is to create two dictionaries: 1) one with the ids as keys and the commented text as values and 2) the second with ids as keys and the comments as values.

Then I plan to run through both dictionaries and if their keys (i.e. ids) match up, I want to make tuples of matching commented text/comment pairs. I'm having trouble creating a dictionary and I'm getting the error message that my syntax for creating the dictionary is invalid. I don't quite understand why. Any ideas?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
f = open('transcript.xml','r')
soup = Soup(f)
#print soup.prettify()

textdict = {}
for i in soup.find_all('w:commentrangestart'):

       # variable 'key' is assigned to the tag id
    key = i.parent.contents[1].attrs['w:id']

       #variable 'value' is assigned to the tag's text
    value= ''.join(i.nextSibling.findAll(text=True)

       # key / value pairs are added to the dictionary 'text_d'
    textdict[key]=value

print textdict

commentdict = {}
for i in soup.find_all('w:comment'):
    key = i.attrs['w:id']
    value= ''.join(i.findAll(text=True)
    commentdict[key]=value
print commentdict

## OUTPUT {u'1': u'contradictory about news', u'0': u'something about news'}
##        {u'1': u'News; comment; negative', u'0': u'News; comment'}

## Added Code
for key in set(textdict) & set (commentdict):
    if textdict[key] == commentdict[key]:
        print 'yay'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error because you didn't close a parenthesis:

```
value= ''.join(i.nextSibling.findAll(text=True)
                                # -------------^ missing )
```

You are missing another a few lines further on too:

```
value= ''.join(i.findAll(text=True)
                    # -------------^ missing )
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that!!!